# Where is the cluster tab in maas?

Tags: 14.04, gui, maas, cluster

That might sound like a silly question but where is the cluster tab? I can't find it on `Mass` web GUI Version: `2.0.0~beta3+bzr4941-0ubuntu1`. 
Here's the actual nav bar:

[image: actual bar]
and this is the one I should have:

[image: bar that I should have]

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think you gonna like the answer.

According to https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/changelog.html cluster controllers have been deprecated and replaced by rack controllers. Cluster tab was removed and at least at this moment configuration can only be seen/modified by using CLI:

```
maas your-maas-profile rack-controllers read
```

Some of configuration could also be seen/modified in Networks tab https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/rack-configuration.html#rack-configuration

**Edit.** Just few moments ago I have discovered you can actually view the status of controller in MAAS GUI > Nodes by clicking on Controllers:

[image]

I wonder myself how I have missed it out. Oh well, live and learn :)